# R1Soft shows server type as "Virtual" but server is physical

Tags: windows-server-2012, hyper-v, r1soft

I've added my server, deployed the backup agent, rebooted my server and it shows " Server Type: Virtual (Hyper V) ".

But my server is a physical server, running Hyper-V. As my license is for a Physical Server, this causes issues.

Any reason why this would be..

Comment: You should really asked R1soft support to answer this question...

Answer (score 0):

Reply from license supplier:

"our physical licenses cover both virtual and physical servers. It's just a graphical bug you can safely ignore."